# prepositions + somebody/something + being or - + done

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, prepositional-phrases

I just don't understand when to use "being" in those situations? What is the logic being them?

> 1- An earlier draft of the law proposed in August 2011 sparked
>   widespread criticism for allowing such detentions ***without families
>   being informed***.
>
> 2- An earlier draft of the law proposed in August 2011 sparked
>   widespread criticism for allowing such detentions ***without families
>   informed***.
>
> 3- I've been surprised how much they can achieve ***without me being
>   involved***.
>
> 4- I've been surprised how much they can achieve ***without me involved***.
>
> 5- Send the email ***with the file being attached***.
>
> 6- Send the email ***with the file attached***.
>
> 7- My boyfriend and I had lots of arguments as a result ***of*** ***me
>   being stressed*** about my workload.
>
> 8- My boyfriend and I had lots of arguments as a result ***of me
>   stressed*** about my workload.

I made out 2,4,5,8 and took the rest from the internet to understand the issue. I can give the sources: for the 7 (https://www.theguardian.com/voluntary-sector-network/2015/jul/26/live-breathe-charity-work-but-burnout-wake-up-call), for the 3 (https://www.nytimes.com/2010/01/31/business/31corner.html) , for the 1 (https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-china-17296145)

Comment: Where did you get them? 4) is odd.

Comment: 2) is right for you two? She's obviously made them up to explore the issue... perfectly sensible approach AFAIC.

Comment: I don't think you make stuff up and then say: What is the logic. I think you are asked to identify incorrect or correct things. 2) and 7) are also wrong. That's true.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I'm inclined to think the present or absence of ***being*** in #3 can reflect a slight nuance of difference. The word ***involved*** is optional there anyway if we also discard ***being***, but ignoring that I think including ***being*** slightly more carries the implication that at some earlier point I ***was*** involved (and they're doing quite well now even after I pulled out). Without ***being*** it seems to me equally likely that I was never involved in the first place.

Comment: Sorry I made out 2,4,5,8 and took the rest from the internet. I can give the source for the 7 (https://www.theguardian.com/voluntary-sector-network/2015/jul/26/live-breathe-charity-work-but-burnout-wake-up-call)

Comment: #8 is non-idiomatic, but note that ***me being stressed*** is a ***noun phrase*** in this context. And as [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+result+of+my+being%2Ca+result+of+me+being&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20result%20of%20my%20being%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20result%20of%20me%20being%3B%2Cc0) shows, most people would use the possessive form *as a result of **my** being stressed*.

Comment: I think @TypeIA and Lambie probably meant 8), not 7). I know I did.

Comment: @Minty The question has been edited since I commented; at the time 7) was blatantly wrong (maybe a typo). I will delete my comment.

Answer (score 1):

As a native American English speaker, both versions are roughly interchangeable.

However, "being + [verb]" implies to me a stronger focus on the action behind something, while words that end in "-ed" imply more of an adjective.

For 1/2, I would prefer 1 as it focuses on the **action** of informing families, instead of the fact that families are informed.

For 3/4, it really depends on whether or not you want to focus on the action of involving "me" or the fact that I am involved. The action implies that we should do something to ensure that "me" is involved.

For 5/6, I would prefer "with the file attached" as it more strongly implies a focus on the file itself, rather than the action of attaching the file.

For 7/8, it really depends on your own preference. I think 7 is softer as it focuses on the action of being stressed as the source of the problem, while 8 is harsher in that it basically implies that "me" is the source of the problem and "me" just happens to be stressed.  However, as FumbleFingers pointed out, "as a result of my being stressed" is more common than "as a result of me being stressed" as this [n-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20result%20of%20my%20being%2Ca%20result%20of%20me%20being&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20result%20of%20my%20being%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20result%20of%20me%20being%3B%2Cc0) shows

With the grammar explanation below, you can see that **present participle** and **past participle** have very similar usages.

---

"Being" is an example of the **present participle** (typically words ending in '-ing').

The present participle is interesting as it can be used as an adjectives, verb phrases, or participle clauses.

Example as an adjective:

> There was a **leaking** pipe.

Example as a verb phrase:

> The pipe was **leaking**.

Example as a participle phrase:

> I am next to the pipe **leaking** water.

Source: 
https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/present_participle.htm

If you want to know more specifically about the verb tense "being": https://www.englishgrammar.org/uses-of-being/

---

On the other hand, the **past participle** are typically words that end in "-ed", "-d", "-t", "-en", or "-n".

They can similarly be used as adjectives, verb phrases, or participle clauses.

Example as an adjective:

> The **exhausted** boy ran home.

Example as a verb phrase:

> The boy was **exhausted** after running home

Example as a participle phrase:

> The boy, **exhausted** from a long day at school, ran home.

Source: https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/past_participles.htm

I hope this helps!

EDIT: Changed the numbering and added FumbleFinger's suggestion

Comment: I certainly don't think the examples are all "interchangeable". #5 is at the very least "dubious", but #2 and #8 are completely unacceptable so far as I'm concerned.

Comment: I agree that #2 sounds wrong without an explanation of what the families are informed about (such as "without families informed about detentions"), but I feel that it is relatively acceptable but extremely dubious.

Comment: I feel that #8 works because it treats "me stressed about my workload" as a single entity, which is the source of the arguments. I agree that it does sound weird, though.  Similarly, #5 sounds rather odd, and I wouldn't use it myself

Comment: @FumbleFingers what's the rule that makes 2 and 8 incorrect? To me the meaning is very clear.

Comment: @Yeah, I don't understand why 2 and 8 are considered wrong either.

Comment: @pipinstallfrisbee: Suppose you'd just written *To me very clear* in that comment. The meaning would still be crystal clear to me - arguably it would convey even *more* "meaning" than what you actually wrote (because it would be a very strong indication that you weren't a native speaker! :) But it would obviously be "incorrect".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Do you mind clarifying why you consider #2 and #8 are unacceptable? I agree with you that they do sound _wrong_ but I'm not sure _why_ from a grammar perspective.

Comment: Offhand I can't think of a rule / principle debarring #2, but it seems to relate to the *specific* verbs and subjects involved. I find the exact example as given completely unacceptable, but I wouldn't argue with *It is illegal to interrogate the boy without his mother present*, which is essentially the same construction.

Comment: ...and as to #8, I find that one ***even less*** acceptable, but again I can't say exactly what rule is being broken.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for the fast response! I have to agree that it does sound _off_ with #2 and #8. I saw your earlier post that "my being stressed" is more common than "me being stressed" and I have to agree that that has a much better flow to it. I'll change the post to reflect that, thanks for the great feedback

Comment: @TalhaÖzden I don't believe that 2 or 8 are actually wrong. They simply don't sound natural. (They sound more natural to me than to others, but still unusual.) However, despite sounding unnatural to one degree or another, I believe they are still syntactically correct. (Which doesn't mean they should be used.)